# how to populate a datalist using an ajax request and angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, ajax

I'm new to js and ajax requests and I am trying to wrap my head around a problem.  I have a database of values and I would like to add tags to them.  There will be 2 tags, "category" and "tag".  Currently what happens is that using Flask, a table is rendered in html, and in that table two input fields are added to the end.  Each of these input fields has a datalist attached to it so a user can type in a new tag/category or they can pick from the drop-down.  This is all working fine, but where I am stuck is that I want the tag selection to be filtered by the category that the person has chosen.  So far I have followed some tutorials and gotten an Ajax request working that returns a list of tags that apply to the category selected.  I'm stuck on how to get that list to actually populate that datalist for the tags.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the relevant html

```
<datalist id="cats">
{% for i in userCats %}
<option value= {{ i }} >
{% endfor %}
</datalist>

{% for item in tableList %}
    <tr>
        {% for i in item[1:] %}
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
        {% endfor %}

    <td><input type="text" name= "cat_{{ item[0] }}" list="cats"></td>

    <td><input type="text" name= "tag_{{ item[0] }}" list="tags_option{{ item[0] }}"></td>
    <datalist id="tag_option{{ item[0] }} ">

    </datalist>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready to go!");

$("form :input").change(function() {
    console.log("change!");

    formNumber = $(this).attr('name');
    category = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/taglist",
        data: {'number': formNumber, 'category':category},

        success: function(results){
            console.log(results['number'])
            $(results['tags']).each(function(index, item){
                console.log(item)
                var option = $('<option value="'+item+'"></option>');
                console.log(option)
                $(results['number']).append(option)
            });


        }

    });

    });
```

Comment: check for ng-repeat

Comment: I suggest you to use ng-repeat directive. Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp